# Prove Length function to count char array element number

Tags: frama-c, formal-verification

I'm trying to prove a function like strlen in C, but frama-c don't prove the 
post condition and the `loop variant len` clause. I can't understand why!

What I've tried:

```c
/*@
    axiomatic elementNumber_axioms
    {
        logic unsigned elementNumber{L}(char *a);

        axiom elementNumber_base{L}:
            elementNumber(\null) == 0;

        axiom elementNumber_step{L}:
            \forall char *a;
            \valid(a) ==> elementNumber(a) == elementNumber(a+1) + 1;
    }
*/

/*@
    assigns \nothing;
    ensures \result == elementNumber(\old(s));
*/
unsigned stringlen(const char *s)
{
    unsigned len = 0;

/*@
    loop assigns len;
    loop assigns s;
    loop variant len;
*/
    while(*s)
    {
        ++s;
        ++len;
    }

    return len;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with what you have written.  A non-exhaustive list:

- Your stringlen() does not handle the case where `s` is NULL.

  If annotating the standard C strlen() function, you would not need to handle this case because the standard C strlen() function does not allow the parameter to be `NULL`.  However, the axiomatic definition of your elementNumber() logic function defines `elementNumber(\null)` to be 0, and a postcondition of stringlen() is that the result equals `elementNumber(s)`.  Thus, you would need to handle this case.
- The while loop in stringlen() terminates when encountering a nul byte.  However, the definition of your elementNumber() logic function only depends on whether a pointer is valid.
- There are no preconditions on stringlen() as to whether `s`, `s + 1`, etc. are valid.
- Your elementNumber() logic function does not define a value for an invalid pointer.
- You will need to specify loop invariants.

---

I recommend taking a look at how Frama-C annotates strlen():

```c
/*@ requires valid_string_src: valid_string(s);
  @ assigns \result \from s[0..];
  @ ensures \result == strlen(s);
  @*/
extern size_t strlen (const char *s);
```

The strlen() logic function and valid_string() predicate are defined in `share/libc/__fc_string_axiomatic.h` of the source distribution, which as of this writing is Sodium-20150201.